# Can't read an uploaded file with Ruby's Framework Padrino

Tags: ruby, file-upload, padrino, net-ftp

I have this form for uploading files:

```
-# coding: utf-8
- content_for(:body_classes, "body3")
.content
  - form_tag url(:images, :create), :method => :post, :multipart => true do
    = file_field_tag :file
    = submit_tag "Upload"
```

And this Controller to handle it:

```
Fbapp.controllers :images do

  get :new do
    render 'images/new'
  end

  post :create do
    require 'net/ftp'
    file = params[:file]
    ftp = Net::FTP.new('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx')
    ftp.passive = true
    ftp.login('user','pass')
    ftp.storbinary("STOR " + "original_filename", StringIO.new(file.read), Net::FTP::DEFAULT_BLOCKSIZE)
    ftp.quit
  end
end
```

And every time I try to upload a file I get "Internal Server Error". And my log has this:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `read' for #<Hash:0x00000003697780>:
```

I'm trying this on Heroku by the way. I can't figure out what's the problem... It seems to work for a lot of people but me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
file = params[:file][:tempfile]
```

and I suggest to retrieve the filename

```
name = params[:file][:filename]
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was missing. Thanks!